# Spring Boot integration test MockBean zero interactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

We have a quite big suite of tests (integration/unit/cucumber....).

Now we want to add an additional integration test using the following code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("integrationTest")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private MyRepository myRepository;

@Test
void myTest() throws Exception {
    
    final var argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyEntity.class);
    mockMvc.perform(
            post(ENDPOINT)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content("{}")
                    .secure(true))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

    verify(myRepository).saveAndFlush(argument.capture());
    final var payload = argument.getValue().getRequest();
    assertThat(payload).doesNotContainAnyWhitespaces();        
}
```

This is MyRepository definition

```
@Repository
public interface RiskScoreRepository extends JpaRepository<..> {}
```

If I run this test only there are no issues. As soon as I run `mvn verify` I get the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
myRepository bean.saveAndFlush(
<Capturing argument>
);
 -> at MyIntegrationTest.registrationWorksThroughAllLayers(MyIntegrationTest.java:XX)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I assume that this is because the Application context is already loaded by a previous integration test.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**
I tried to disable all the others integrations tests and now `MyIntegrationTest` is passing even with `mvn verify`
How can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you assume another test contaminates your test, run only your MyIntegrationTest (or disable the other tests) to verify it.

Comment: Yes, If I run only it, it works. But when I run mvn verify I get that error

Comment: Is `MyRepository` wired in correctly? Can you confirm in the production/main code, you have an annotation for an equivalent class (of type MyRepository) that has the annotation `@Profile("!integrationTest")`.. Also does `mvn verify` activate the integrationTest profile (check the logs). I suspect the class is not wired in as expected.

Comment: I've added the MyRepository definition in the post. To answer your question, yes mvn verify activate the integrationTest (otherwise all the integration tests won't work)